# Cover and avoidance properties of chief factors: can we avoid exactly the ones we want?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

If $G$ is a finite solvable group with chief series $1 = G_0 \leq \ldots \leq G_n = G$ (so each $G_i \unlhd G$ and if $G_{i-1} < H < G_i$ then $H$ is not normal in $G$) and $I \subseteq \{ 1,\ldots,n\}$.  Does there exist a subgroup $H \leq G$ such that $G_{i-1} H \geq G_i$ when $i \in I$ and $G_i \cap H \leq G_{i-1}$ when $i \notin I$?

In other words, can I choose which chief factors a subgroup covers and avoids?

(If so, can we describe how to find such a subgroup? If not, are there easy properties $I$ needs to have, like containing all the Frattini chief factors?)

---

Here are some example sets $I$ that we can use:

- $I_p = \{ i : [G_i:G_{i-1}] \text{ is divisible by } p \}$, $H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup
- $I_{p'} = \{ i : [G_i:G_{i-i}] \text{ is not divisible by } p \}$, $H$ is a Sylow $p$-complement
- $I_{\pi} = \{ i : [G_i:G_{i-1}] \text{ is a $\pi$-number} \}$, $H$ is a Hall $\pi$-subgroup
- $I_c = \{ i  : G_i/G_{i-1} \leq Z(G/G_{i-1}) \}$, $H$ is a Sylow system normalizer
- $I_\Phi = \{ i : G_i/G_{i-1} \leq \Phi(G/G_{i-1}) \}$, then $H$ is a pre-Frattini subgroup

Indeed these can almost by used as definitions for the $H$ (there is a technical condition about behaving well with a Sylow system for the last one or two, I think). All of these subgroups exist in every finite soluble group.

Do the allowable $I$ at least form a Boolean algebra? $I_c \cup I_\Phi$ is allowable (by Hawkes, though I don't know the details). What about the complement of $I_c$?

Comment: **Negative answer:** The cyclic group of order 4 has a unique chief series, and the allowable $I$ are exactly $\{\}$, $\{1\}$, and $\{1,2\}$; closed under union and intersection, but not complements. The dihedral group of order 24 has many chief series: for some the allowable $I$ are closed under unions, and for some they are not; all are closed under intersection. There are $G$ such that the allowable $I$ are/are not closed under intersection.

Comment: I'm still looking for any kind of positive answer.

Comment: The group ${\rm SL}_2(3)$ has chief factors $2$, $2^2$, and $3$, where the first and third are central and the second not. So I don't believe that the complement of $I_c$ is allowable in this group.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure what other positive statements are left to disprove. My current theoretical knowledge is: **Positive results:** we can enlarge $I_c$ to $\mathfrak{F}$-central for (things like) formations $\mathfrak{F}$ and we can union with $I_\Phi$ by Hawkes's result that an $\mathfrak{F}$-normalizer normalizes a pre-frattini subgroup (so take the subgroup generated by both). I think I can intersect with $I_\pi$ by choosing $\pi$-subgroups but I haven't checked details, and I can union with $I_\pi$ since I can include a permuting Hall $\pi$-subgroup.

Comment: If anyone is working on this, you might email me. I have a draft answer written, but am having some difficulties with prefrattini subgroups.